# Repository Pattern best Practices

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

My apology as this question is difficult to express with nice words.

I have question similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669799/call-methods-between-repositories-repository-pattern).

Is it violation of Repository Pattern? to use Reposiotry created for Product is used to get all Categories?

```
        viewModel.Categories= productRepository.FindAll<Category>(c => c.Id > 0).ToList();//is it Correct with Pattern
```

Though I can get similar result with this also,

```
        viewModel.Categories = categoryRepository.GetAll();// getting Categories by creating new instance of categoryRepository
```

In above example I need to show categories on Product view, only diplay no crud(unit of work) will be done on Category.
So what is best practice here?

Thnaks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [mentioned in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265872/asp-net-mvc-repository-pattern-understanding), you probably want to have a ServiceLayer in between. The service layer is responsible to decouple meta logic from your controller. As your code grows more complex, there will be a need for repositories knowing each other, which is not good. For a service, however, it's perfectly OK. Repositories then are very light-weight and have no understanding of the business logic.

The ServiceLayer, however, has. For example, if there is no `Categories` Collection/Table, but the Categories are embedded in the Products, there shouldn't be a CategoryRepository that pretends. A `ProductService` could suplly a method `AllCategories()`, however.

Comment: Thanks, but dosen't repository should handle its own class? here in case ProductRepository should be handling all the work related to product and NOT category related

Comment: It depends on the way you use categories. If you are using a RDMBS and Categories is a table and each product has a foreign key to a product, then `Category` is a separate entity that also has a `CategoryRepository`. These typically support CRUD operations. If, however, you just assign a free-form category to each product, there is no 'add category' method, so there is no `CategoryRepository` either. Like you said, the `ProductRepository` is never concerned with the categories, but the `ProductService` might be.

Comment: Going for this->"For a service, however, it's perfectly OK. Repositories then are very light-weight and have no understanding of the business logic."